# How to create a html form webpart filter for 2 list columns

Tags: javascript, web-part, filter, html, data-view-web-part

I have a html form webpart (in the form of textbox input). I would like to filter 2 list columns using the same webpart:

[image]

So instead of the usual filtering for 1 list column, this webpart will be used to search 2 list columns (Name column and phone number column). How do I go about creating such a webpart? The connections option for this webpart only allows connecting to 1 list column:

[image]

**EDIT**: I realized for this method, even for just 1 list column connection, it doesn't work at all. Should I be using javascript instead? If yes, how do I go about coding the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://sudhirke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/jquery-cool-filters-for-sharepoint-list/) is what you are looking for. It allows to filter by multiple fields using JavaScript.

So, you will be able to filter by Name field or Phone number field.